# Invoking AmazonPay and Bhim app from my App using deeplink for iOS

Tags: payment, upi, amazon-pay

Deeplink is working fine in iOS with all other apps other than amazonpay as well as Bhim app.

> amazonToAlipay://pay

> BHIM://pay

But it is not redirecting though I have amazon as well as bhim app.

Can you suggest me which deeplink used for this 2 apps for iOS?